# Showing a fragment throws Null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have a android app that is targeted for api level 9 and users app compat library. So I have this issue when I click a button it should show a fragment, but I dont know why this is not possible, because its showing me this error in log cat:

```
/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp, PID: 14290
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.myapp.Main.onClick(Main.java:1204)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the error I get:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("--", "view clicked");
        if (adapter != null)
            if (!menuShown && adapter.getNextPrayTime() != null) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.action_share:
                        View view = findViewById(R.id.main_rl);
                        shareImage(view, false);
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_menu:
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putSerializable(Constants.NEXT_TIME,
                                adapter.getNextPrayTime());
                        MenuFragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
                        menuFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        Log.e("--",menuFragment+" ex. "+bundle);
    //this is line 1204
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                        transaction.setCustomAnimations(
                                R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom,
                                R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom,
                                R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom,
                                R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom);
                        transaction.add(android.R.id.content, menuFragment);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                        menuShown = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
    }
```

Does anyone have a idea why is this happening so I can solve this issue?

Thanks

**Edit:** this activity extends `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: have you built the jar android-support-v4.jar ?

Comment: Show on click method.

Comment: are you sure this is line 1204? `getSupportFragmentManager` cannot return `null`

Comment: @Hulk I have the android-support-v4.jar inside of the libs folder and in my gradle i have: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`

Comment: ok well the main thing is the type of fragment you are importing since you are using api less than 11. I am sure you must be importing support v4 fragment. Do a little change. extend your activity from fragmentactivity

Comment: @PiyushGupta code in the question is updated

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski Can you tell exact which line you'r getting error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```